# Doctrine 2 Inheritance Mapping Strategy Advice needed

Tags: php, mapping, doctrine-orm

I'll try to explain my problem. Shortly, I have address table, rooms table, buildings table and users tables. Address table should be able to keep address for rooms, buildings and users by their ID's of course. Since I can't use direct Association Mapping I need an inheritance mapping. Let me make this clear that I'm not good at inheritance mapping issue. My solution is to create an Alias table which keeps the ID of the rooms, buildings and users (also their class names) and address table can interact directly with this Alias table. So in SQL style this would be join Alias and users then join the address table find the user's address. However, I couldn't decide which mapping style would fit. Can you give me some advice about it and give me a short explanation why it is like that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use relations like
I suppose this structure (user can own address, building have address, room have building)

```
users
 address
  buildings
   rooms
```

And code for it

```
/**
 * @orm:Table(name="rooms")
 * @orm:Entity
 */
class Room {
    ....
    /**
     * @orm:InheritanceType("JOINED")
     * @orm:OneToOne(targetEntity="Building")
     * @orm:JoinColumn(name="bid", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     */
    private $building;
    ....
}

/**
 * @orm:Table(name="Buildings")
 * @orm:Entity
 */
class Building {
    ....
    /**
     * @orm:InheritanceType("JOINED")
     * @orm:OneToOne(targetEntity="Address")
     * @orm:JoinColumn(name="aid", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;
    ....
}

/**
 * @orm:Table(name="rooms")
 * @orm:Entity
 */
class Address {
    ....
    /**
     * @orm:InheritanceType("JOINED")
     * @orm:OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @orm:JoinColumn(name="uid", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;
    ....
}

/**
 * @orm:Table(name="users")
 * @orm:Entity
 */
class User {
....
}
```

`@orm:` needs when using doctrine with symfony

Comment: Thank you, but there is no inheritance in this structure, it is one to one join structure. I think I have found what would fit my needs is Class Table Inheritance because I need Discriminator Columns. Whenever I finish coding I'll post code here.